# react native why my absolute view is not showing all only the half?

Tags: react-native, expo

why my purple absolute view is not showing all, only the half ?

look at the image[image]

Code:

CardView:

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const MAX_NAME_WIDTH = width / 2 - 48;

const CARD_WIDTH = width * 0.45;

const UserCardAdvanced = ({ user_id, username, profile_image, followingShops, is_verification, isD, stars, onPress, onPressReviews, onPressFollow }: IUserCardAdvanced) => {
  return (
    <Pressable onPress={onPress} style={s.card}>
      { isD &&
        <PurpleNotice />
      }
      <Image source={{uri: profile_image}} resizeMode='contain' style={s.profile_image} />
      <View style={s.starContainer}>
        <Stars 
          star_filled={stars?.fill}
          disabled
          is_all
          size={15}
          onPressAll={onPressReviews}
        />
        <Text style={s.reviewTotal}>{stars?.total_reviews}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={s.nameContainer}>
        <NameWithVerification
          name={username}
          is_verification={is_verification}
          nameStyle={s.nameStyle}
        />
      </View>
      <FollowBtn
        onPress={onPressFollow}
        is_followed={false}
        size={24}
      />
    </Pressable>
  )
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    padding: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 3,
    margin: 6,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
    zIndex: 99921,
    width: CARD_WIDTH
  },
  starContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 8
  },
  reviewTotal: {
    fontFamily: globalStyles.font_regular,
    color: '#333',
    marginLeft: 4
  },
  nameContainer: {
    marginVertical: 8
  },
  nameStyle: {
    color: '#333',
    fontSize: 13,
    maxWidth: MAX_NAME_WIDTH
  },
  profile_image: {
    height: 84,
    width: 84,
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
  username: {
    fontFamily: globalStyles.font_regular,
    color: '#555',
    marginTop: 12,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
})
```

Purple Notice

```
const PurpleNotice = (isD: isD) => {
  return (
    <View style={s.view}>
      <Text style={s.text}>TESTTESTETS</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    padding: 2,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: globalStyles.globalColor,
    borderRadius: 6,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -10,
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 99999
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: globalStyles.font_light,
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 11,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    textShadowColor: '#fff',
    textShadowOffset: {
      height: 2,
      width: 2
    }
  }
});
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong i am very thankful for your help!!

.........................................
.........................................
.........................................
.........................................
.........................................

Comment: What's the CardView in front of? It looks like the `top: -10` in PurpleNotice might be pushing it out of the bounds of the parent view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `zIndex={1}` to that purple view.

Answer (score 0):

use right:0 in style

```
const s = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    padding: 2,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: globalStyles.globalColor,
    borderRadius: 6,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -10,
    left: 0,
    right:0, //use this also
    zIndex: 99999
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: globalStyles.font_light,
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 11,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    textShadowColor: '#fff',
    textShadowOffset: {
      height: 2,
      width: 2
    }
  }
});
```